# Excel two conditional formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

Is there a way to have a cell reference to two rules in conditional formatting?

As a teacher I have a spreadsheet of the grades of 26 children.

Column A: Target = 100
Column B: Actual scores of test 1
Column C: Actual scores of test 2 (taken a month after test 1)
Column D: Difference between column C and column B (to see if their scores went up or down or stay flat after a month)
Column E: How far the score of test 2 is from the target

Is there a way to use Icon Sets so that if the scores go down from test 1 to test 2 (i.e., shows a down arrow), but the score of test 2 is within range of the target, then it will be a green down arrow?

Vice versa, if the scores go up from test 1 to test 2 (i.e., shows an up arrow), but the score of test 2 is only 20 out of 100, for example (out of range of the target), then it will be a red up arrow?

I can do the two separately by using the difference formula, but I can't seem to get both of them to work at the same time.

Comment: I don't think you can do that with the inbuilt icon sets, though if you were amenable to using different icons, this article may be of interest - http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2013/09/03/create-your-own-excel-icon-set/

Answer (score 0):

If you want icons, I think you'll need to add a column to calculate the summary. If both C and D are ‘bad’ when the value is negative, and they have the same scale, then this formula in column E should do what you need:

```
=MIN(C2,D2)
```

You can then apply the conditional formatting to column E.

If all you want is fill or font changes, then you can use an `AND()` or `OR()` function to combine conditions in your conditional format. You can read more about how to [use formulas in conditional formatting here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-formulas-with-conditional-formatting-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f), but assuming your data is in row 2, the following formula should do what you need:

```
=OR(D2>0,C2<0)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, with the built-in Icon Sets it is not possible to have a green down arrow or a red up arrow, let alone having *both* red and green up and down arrows at the same time.

However, what you are after *is* possible by using arrow characters, combined with a conditional formatting formula rule to set the colours. An extra column is also required if you wish to display the test score differences as well as the arrows.

The following screenshot shows some sample data, the key formulae used, and the resulting arrows:

[image: screenshot of spreadsheet]

**Setup:**

Enter the following formulae into the designated cells:

`E2` → `=C2-B2`

`F2` → `=C2-A2`

`D2` → `=CHOOSE(2+SIGN(E2),"È","Æ","Ç")`

and copy-paste/fill-down/ctrl-enter them into the rest of the table.

Set two conditional formatting formula rules for column `D` of the table (e.g., `$D$2:$D$8`):

`=F2 <0` → red font colour
`=F2>=0` → green font colour

Finally, set the font and size of column `D` of the table (`$D$2:$D$8`) appropriately for the characters chosen. (In this example I'm using the 14pt bold Wingdings 3   characters.)

**Notes:**

- The order of the characters in the `D2` formula is "down arrow", "side-ways arrow", and then "up arrow".

---

The other table is just to demonstrate some possible arrows and colours that you could use. I have repeated the table below so you can copy-paste the characters directly:

```
  Wingdings 3   Wingdings    Calabri    
11pt 14pt_bold  14pt_bold   11pt_bold   
ã       Ç       ñ   ñ       ↑   ↑
ã       Ç       ñ   ñ       ↑   ↑
â       Æ       ð   ó       →   ↔
â       Æ       ð   ó       →   ↔
â       Æ       ð   ó       →   ↔
ä       È       ò   ò       ↓   ↓
ä       È       ò   ò       ↓   ↓
```

Answer (score -1):

If you make a formula like the following:

[image: formula]

Then you have a column E with a positive number if they have increased the result and a negative value if they have decreased the score.

Then mark the column and choose:

Conditional formating  -> New rule

[image: new custom formating]

And add a custom formating like this.

[image: custom format with icons]